# Apply bootstrap css and my custom css to child component from parent component

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-cli

I have a parent component with bootstrap top navbar (with my custom css) template like this:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template:'<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li routerLinkActive="active">
                    <a routerLink="home" translate><i class="fa fa-home" 
                       aria-hidden="true"></i>Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li routerLinkActive="active">
                    <a routerLink="home" translate><i class="fa fa-home" 
                       aria-hidden="true"></i>Projects</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <app-translate></app-translate>
                    <li routerLinkActive="active">
                     <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-circle" 
                        aria-hidden="true"></i>SignUp</a>
                    </li>
                    <li routerLinkActive="active">
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-
                        hidden="true"></i>Login</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

And this is my translate component:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-translate',
 template: ' <li routerLinkActive="active">
              <a href="#" translate><i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-
                hidden="true"></i>test</a>
             </li>',
 styleUrls: ['./translate.component.css']
})
export class TranslateComponent {
}
```

In my app-translate component i want the achieve the normal behavior of a list, and apply all the bootstrap css and my custom css from parent component and add my own custon css to translate component. But the result is not as expected. How can i achieve this?

Comment: why do you want to apply the styles from parent component? Bootstrap classes and your custom css classes should be available to all components if you load them in angular-cli.json or in index file.

Comment: yes i know, but i want that the app-translate componett will inherit all the css classes from bootstap and from the app-root. i dont want to override the css of bootstrap., If i will do that, i will not able to see the app-root  content. @NishadAhsan

Comment: okay. You can try using *ngIf or has.class directives and property binding. But that might get messy if you have a lot of them.

Comment: why not make use of `viewEncapsulation` allows the styles to flow down to child . check [this](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/view)